# Hartshorne Exercise 1.2.9 Projective Closure of Affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $Y\subset \mathbb A^n$ is an affine variety, we identify $\mathbb A^n$ with the open set $U_0\subset \mathbb P^n$ by the homeomorphism $\phi_0$ (defined in his proposition 2.2). Let $\overline{Y}$ be the closure of $Y$ in $\mathbb P^n$.

The question (a) asks us to show $I(\overline{Y})$ is the ideal generated by $\beta(I(Y))$.

However, I actually "showed" that $I(\overline{Y})=\beta(I(Y))$, not just the ideal generated by it! Here is the proof of $\subset$ part: If $f\in I(\overline{Y})$, then $f=\beta(g)$, where $g=f(1,x_1,\dots,x_n)\in I(Y)$.

This shouldn't be correct, because in his part (b), we are asked to disprove that if $f_1,\dots, f_r$ generate $I(Y)$, then $\beta(f_1),\dots, \beta(f_r)$ generate $I(\overline Y)$. But this statement would be true if $I(\overline{Y})=\beta(I(Y))$.

Can anyone clarify this for me or show me the correct proof of that $I(\overline{Y})$ is the ideal generated by $\beta(I(Y))$, in particular the $\subset$ part?

---

Definition of $\beta$:

$\beta:A\to S^h$, given $g\in A$ of degree $e$, then $x_0^e g(x_1/x_0,\dots, x_n/x_0)$.

Comment: Why not define $\beta$ and maybe take an example of $Y$

Comment: @reuns I just added the definition. My question is about finding the mistake of my reasoning for $I(\overline{Y})=\beta(I(Y))$.

Comment: Well, you should include your reasoning then - I don't see it in your post right now.

Comment: @No One Why is any $f\in I(\overline{Y})$ of the form $f=\beta(g)$ with $g=f(1,x_1,\dots,x_n) \in $I(Y)$ as you claim?

Comment: @KReiser In the 3rd paragraph I prove one containment. That should be the place that I have mistakes (though I don't know)

Comment: The equality $f = \beta(g)$ does not hold if $f$ can be divided by some power of $x_0$ or if $f$ is not homogeneous.

Comment: @RobinCarlier When I write $I(\overline Y)$ with $\overline Y\subset \mathbb P^n$,  $I(\overline Y)$ already consists of homogeneous polynomials.

Comment: why do you believe that it can't hold when f can be  divided by some power of $x_0$, $f$ can always be divided by the zero power of $x_0$...

Comment: Some strictly positive power of $x_0$*. Try $f = X^2Y$, then $f(1,Y) = Y$ and $\beta(f) = Y$. Anyway, In Hartshorne's notation (def page 10), $I(\bar{Y})$ is **generated** by homogeneous polynomials vanishing on $\bar{Y}$, but does not only consist of homogeneous polynomials.